# Cylinder number picker in HTML

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

[cylinder scroll menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOxWo.jpg)

I'm trying to create a date picker that isn't an ugly popup calendar. Apple used to have a pseudo-3d cylinder you could scroll up and down by swiping.

Is there a name for this UI element?

I tried searching default bootstrap UI elements and also keyword search but can't find anything on this.

Comment: The apple one just looks like flat lists with some shading/

Comment: the complicated part is looping the list. It needs to wrap around once you hit the end of the list.

Comment: You can follow this url: https://demo.mobiscroll.com/jquery/datetime/mobile-desktop-usage#

Comment: @Raeesh Alam looks great but it's something you need to pay for